# Invalid value for prop `css` when using @emotion/react with Vite

Tags: reactjs, storybook, vite, emotion

I couldn't find any information on how to make [@emotion/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/react) work in [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) when using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) as a bundler in a React application.

I'm getting errors like `Invalid value for prop 'css' in <div> tag` in almost every story.
Even though, @emotion/react is working fine for the webapp itself.

Here's my `vite.config.js` configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    jsxFactory: 'jsx',
    jsxInject: `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'`,
  },
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
      babel: {
        plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

And here's my `main.js` for Storybook:

```
const svgrPlugin = require('vite-plugin-svgr');

module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'storybook-builder-vite',
  },
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  viteFinal: (config, { configType }) => {
    config.define = {
      'window.process': {
        env: {
          NODE_ENV: configType.toLowerCase(),
        },
      },
    };
    return {
      ...config,
      plugins: [
        ...config.plugins,
        svgrPlugin({
          svgrOptions: {
            icon: true,
          },
        }),
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found in [storybook-builder-vite](https://github.com/eirslett/storybook-builder-vite)'s github page [here](https://github.com/eirslett/storybook-builder-vite/issues/210).

Comment: While the answer might address the question, posting only links is not encouraged because the target page might cease to exist in the future. While links are allowed, always consider to include at least the relevant content to your question.